# jquery - variable as parameter of function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, select

I have a multiple select:

```
<select name="courier" class="selectpicker courierpicker" multiple>
    <option value="value1">Value1</option>
    <option value="value2">Value2</option>
    ...
</select>
```

I want to use selected options as parameters for filtering rows in my table. This code doesn't work for me (assume, just for this example, that there is always more than one selected option):

```
$(".selectpicker").change(function() {
    var items = [];
    $('.courierpicker option:selected').each(function(){ 
        items.push($(this).val()); 
    });
    var $result = '["' + items.join('","') + '"]';
    $('#data-table').bootstrapTable('filterBy', {
        courierfilter: $result
    });
});
```

When I trigger:

```
$('#data-table').bootstrapTable('filterBy', { 
    courierfilter: ["value1","value2"] 
});
```

Everything works just fine.

I know it will be some stupid mistake of the beginner, but thanks in advance for every help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `courierfilter` property expects an array, yet you're providing it a string which is formatted like an array. Also note that the array generation can be made simpler through the use of the `map()` method. Try this:

```
$(".selectpicker").change(function() {
    var items = $('.courierpicker option:selected').map(function(){ 
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    $('#data-table').bootstrapTable('filterBy', {    
        courierfilter: items 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `{courierfilter: items}`.